# Can we write a common class to access the client context multiple times in a code?

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a SharePoint Provider Hosted App. I will have to hit the Client context multiple times to render the data.

I am unable to write a common class in C# Client object Model to access the client context using the class. Is there any possibility to reduce the hits to the context in improving the performance.

Your help over here is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you certainly can re-use the same ClientContext object.  You should pass it around using standard object oriented techniques.

e.g.

```
public class YourClass {

private ClientContext _clientContext;

public YourClass(ClientContext clientContext){ 
_clientContext = clientContext;
}
}
```